# Need Help: Implementing strikethrough for regular price on button - Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a strikethrough effect to the regular price displayed on a button, but it's not rendering correctly, and instead, it shows the HTML text. Can anyone provide assistance with resolving this issue?

[image]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Shop and other archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Single product pages

function custom_add_to_cart_price( $button_text, $product ) {
    // Variable products
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // Shop and archives
        if ( ! is_product() ) {
            $variation_prices = $product->get_variation_prices();
            $min_variation_price = min( $variation_prices['price'] );
            $max_variation_price = max( $variation_prices['price'] );

            $min_price_html = wc_price( $min_variation_price );
            $max_price_html = wc_price( $max_variation_price );

            // If on sale, show both regular and sale prices
            if ( $min_variation_price !== $max_variation_price ) {
                return $button_text . ' - From ' . $min_price_html . ' (Regular: ' . $max_price_html . ')';
            } else {
                return $button_text . ' - From ' . $min_price_html;
            }
        } 
        // Single product pages
        else {
            return $button_text;
        }
    } 
    // All other product types
    else {
        $regular_price = wc_price( $product->get_regular_price() );
        $sale_price = wc_price( $product->get_price() );

        // If on sale, show both regular and sale prices
        if ( $regular_price !== $sale_price ) {
            $regular_price_styled = '<del>' . strip_tags( $regular_price ) . '</del>';
            return strip_tags( $sale_price ) . ' (Regular: ' . $regular_price_styled . ')';
        } else {
            return '' . strip_tags( $sale_price );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the HTML is escaped using `esc_html()` function in all related templates, so you can not use html…